# Database solutions for a prospective (not retrospective) search

Tags: mysql, sql, database, search, nosql

Let's say we have a requirement to create a system that consumes a high-volume, real-time data stream of documents, and that matches those documents against a set of user-defined search queries as those documents become available.  This is a prospective, as opposed to a retrospective, search service.  What would be an appropriate persistence solution?

Suppose that users want to see a live feed of documents that match their queries--think Google Alerts--and that the feed must display certain metadata for each document.  Let's assume an indefinite lifespan for matches; i.e., the system will allow the user to see all of the matches for a query from the time when the particular query was created.  So the metadata for each document that comes in the stream, and the associations between the document and the user queries that matched that document, must be persisted to a database.

Let's throw in another requirement, that users want to be able to facet on some of the metadata: e.g., the user wants to see only the matching documents for a particular query whose metadata field "result type" equals "blog," and wants a count of the number of blog matches.

Here are some hypothetical numbers:

1. 200,000 new documents in the data stream every day.

   -The metadata for every document is persisted.
2. 1000 users with about 5 search queries each: about 5000 total user search queries.

   -These queries are simple boolean queries.

   -As each new document comes in, it is processed against all 5000 queries to see which queries are a match.
3. Each feed--one for each user query--is refreshed to the user every minute.  In other words, for every feed, a query to the database for the most recent page of matches is performed every minute.

Speed in displaying the feed to the user is of paramount importance.  Scalability and high availability are essential as well.

The relationship between users and queries is relational, as is the relationship between queries and matching documents, but the document metadata itself are just key-value pairs.  So my initial thought was to keep the relational data in a relational DB like MySQL and the metadata in a NoSQL DB, but can the faceting requirement be achieved in a NoSQL DB?  Also, constructing a feed would then require making a call to two separate data stores, which is additional complexity.  Or perhaps shove everything into MySQL, but this would entail lots of joins and counts.  If we store all the data as key-value pairs in some other kind of data store, again, how would we do the faceting?  And there would be a ton of redundant metadata for documents that match more than one search query.

What kind of database(s) would be a good fit for this scenario?  I'm aware of tools such as [Twitter Storm](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm) and Yahoo's [S4](http://incubator.apache.org/s4/), which could be used to construct the overall architecture of such a system, but I'd like to focus on the database, given the data storage, volume, and query/faceting requirements.

Comment: Firstly I believe this is off topic for SO. "Shopping list" questions don't have a definitive answer, so I'm voting to close. Secondly, although 200k new records a day sounds like a lot it's not actually. It's 730m a decade and you only need to store the metadata. Plus what are the chances of all 200k being "new"... if they're not all you need is effective de-duplication.

Answer (score 0):

First, I disagree with Ben.  200k new records per day compares with 86,400 seconds in a day, so we are talking about three records per second.  This is not earth shattering, but it is a respectable clip for new data.

Second, I think this is a real problem that people face.  I'm not going to be one that says that this forum is not appropriate for the topic.

I think the answer to the question has a lot to do with the complexity and type of user queries that are supported.  If the queries consist of a bunch of binary predicates, for instance, then you can extract the particular rules from the document data and then readily apply the rules.  If, on the other hand, the queries consist of complex scoring over the text of the documents, then you might need an inverted index paired with a scoring algorithm for each user query.

My approach to such a system would be to parse the queries into individual data elements that can be determined from each document (which I might call a "queries signature" since the results would contain all fields needed to satisfy the queries).  This "queries signature" would be created each time a document was loaded, and it could then be used to satisfy the queries.

Adding a new query would require processing all the documents to assign new values.  Given the volume of data, this might need to be more of a batch task.

Whether SQL is appropriate depends on the features that you need to extract from the data.  This in turn depends on the nature of the user queries.  It is possible that SQL is sufficient.  On the other hand, you might need more sophisticated tools, especially if you are using text mining concepts for the queries.

Comment: I didn't say that the topic is inappropriate for this Q&A site [(not a forum)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/is-stackoverflow-a-forum) merely that the question was. As demonstrated by your answer which contains 9 conditional statements, an indicator that the question was too broad.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking about this, it sounds like an event-processing task, rather than a regular data processing operation, so it might be worth investigating [Complex Event Processing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_event_processing) systems - rather than building everything on a regular database, using a system which processes the queries on the incoming data as it streams into the system. There are commercial systems which can hit the speed & high-availability criteria, but I haven't researched the available OSS options (luckily, people on [quora](http://www.quora.com/Complex-Event-Processing-CEP/Are-there-any-open-source-CEP-tools) have done so).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Elastic Search. It has a percolator feature that matches a document against registered queries.
http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/2011/02/08/percolator.html